# How to change colour of dialogue window?

Tags: window

[image]

I wanted dialogue window colour to be changed. But home screen's title bar colour should not be changed. To understand better I had attached a picture here.

Comment: You may want to consider using a different desktop environment or a different Ubuntu flavor. GNOME is not designed to be easily customizable in this way.

Comment: @Nmath can you pls suggest such Ubuntu flavours?

Comment: Every other flavor has a better customization kit than GNOME does without having to install additional software. In particular, Xfce (Xubuntu) and KDE (Kubuntu), give you tons of options.  If you want to try a new DE I would recommend that you first run a live session from installation media before installing a new desktop.  It can be a bit messy to switch desktop environments on an installed system

Comment: That is a screenshot from Unity, not Gnome 3...

Comment: Are you still using Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Yes @Levente. Unable to increase my laptop ram from 2gb to 4gb in this lock down period. My laptop works well in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 16.04 (an OS with its standard support expired) imposes two difficulties on you: one is that unfortunately [you cannot get answers to your questions on this site](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19582/1157519); the other one that neither your operating system, neither your applications (such as your web-browser) do not get any security patches any more. Browsing the web with such a machine could set you up for trouble sooner or later.

Comment: Your second issue, regarding the security patches, might be mitigated if you subscribe for the [Ubuntu Extended Security Maintenance scheme](https://ubuntu.com/security/esm), which, depending on your use-case, might cost nothing; as in: you may get it for free, for personal use.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try out whether [Lubuntu or Xubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) (the two lightest-weight full-desktop-experience distributions currently) could run in a satisfactory manner on your current hardware configuration. (Booting from an USB stick preloaded with their installers correspondingly will allow you to test them in "Try Ubuntu without installing" mode.)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answers, @Levente. If I increase my laptop's ram from 2GB to 4GB can I run Ubuntu 20.04 smoothly and navigate multiple windows fastly ?

Comment: Well, it's a difficult question to answer... I personally would say: probably no. You can search this site for the keyword: "swappiness", and sort for "newest". I think a lot of questions / answers will disclose how much RAM people having swap issues have.

Comment: But, even though I don't use them currently, I do believe that 4GB of RAM could be enough to run Xubuntu or Lubuntu at acceptable speeds.