# Ubuntu initramfs decoding failed. Someone help. While dual booting btw

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, live-usb, usb-installation

[image]

I rlly need some help. I tried going through so many solutions. Bitlocker is off. AHCI mode. I already had ubuntu installed but I wiped its partition to install windows 10. Now I want to switch back but this error shows up. My laptop is a dell inspiron 3542 btw.
Specs are intel i3_4005u@1.7ghz,intel hd4400 igpu, 500gb hdd, 4gb ram.

Comment: The initramfs error message is very common, and very often it does not cause these issues. Which means that I personally don't see the connection between the initramfs message and the rest of your problem proven. You could try focusing your question title on "Kernel panic — not syncing: No working init found."...

Comment: @levente I can't install ubuntu. It appears whenever I try to install it using a usb flash drive.

Comment: Yes, it did the same for me. And when I finally overcame the issue (by reinstalling Grub, as far as I remember), and Ubuntu was finally up and running, the initramfs message kept showing up. Except for, it did not cause any visible detriment any more. That's why I said, its presence may be misleading.

Comment: By the way, some people would recommend, repeat the process of putting the installer ISO file on the USB stick. Just to be sure that it got written correctly. Also, you could test it for yourself: Boot from the USB and use it in "Try Ubuntu without installing" mode. When it's up, look in the logs (there is a Logs app). The initramfs error will be in the logs; even though the OS is happily chugging along.

Comment: There is no try ubuntu without installing mode. When I boot it there is a like options to install ubuntu, safe graphics, uefi firmware and boot from next partition or something. When I click any of it it shows that initramfs error. Should I try a different distro or an older one?

Comment: That sounds like an idea... From the tags I see your attempt is at 20.04. Maybe you could install 18.04 (the previous LTS), and upon a successful installation, without customizing anything, you could immediately perform the upgrade to 20.04...

Comment: Sure I'll try. I am worried it may be a problem with my computer. I had it up running and then I installed windows 10 wiping ubuntu completely. Next time I try it won't work.

Comment: Guess what it worked. Tysm dude. Wish I can friend add you are follow you. No option for it :(    . Ubuntu 16.04 works.

Comment: O.k. but you are not done yet. 16.04 is sorely out of support (too old already), so much so that this website does not even answer new questions about it any more. You need to do the upgrade now. To get more info on why and how 16.04 is out of support and why it's a challenge, see the comments here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1342277/how-to-change-colour-of-dialogue-window#comment2293435_1342277

Comment: If you don't really customize much on the current install, then hopefully the upgrade would go smoothly...

Comment: Ye. I sure hope all goes well.

Comment: Ye it went well. Despite the fact it took so long. I finally upgraded it to 20.04. I had to upgrade to 18.04 and then 20.04 lol.